# image shared to Snapchat using UIActivityViewController gets zoomed and cropped

Tags: ios, swift, image, share, snapchat

I'm having problems with sharing images with UIActivityViewController to snapchat. Shared images are zoomed and cropped (it works fine with other apps: facebook, messenger, notes, twitter, viber, iCloud...).

Here is my code:

```
let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [waterMarkedImage], applicationActivities: nil)

avc.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
     self.setTimer()
}
self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: self.stopTimer)
```

The result - shared image is cropped:

[image]